# Two seperate DIV's with underlying images don't float to the right side

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the page split in half. On one side there's an image of a computer monitor with a blue transparent overlay. This will become brighter when hovered over. The same is on the right side with a different image (of a music manuscript). However, this doesn't work in practice and just collapses to one single DIV block on the left side.

Code:

```css
html, body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
}

div.leftImage {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/270360/pexels-photo-270360.jpeg?w=940&h=650&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-position: 45%;
}

div.rightImage {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/BWV605.png");
  background-position: center;
}

div.left {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.left:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.8);
}

div.right {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  display: block;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.right:hover {
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="leftImage">
  </div>
  <div class="rightImage">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `position: absolute`, layout properties like `float: left` won't have any effect.

Instead, use the `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` properties to control absolute-positioned elements:

```css
html, body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
}

div.leftImage {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/270360/pexels-photo-270360.jpeg?w=940&h=650&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-position: 45%;
}

div.rightImage {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/BWV605.png");
  background-position: center;
}

div.left {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.left:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.8);
}

div.right {
  /*Set up positioning:*/
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  /*Set up the background:*/
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.right:hover {
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.8);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="leftImage">
  </div>
  <div class="rightImage">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="left">
    <p>Test.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another simple alternative to avoid floats altogether. Make use of flexbox and you don't need to float or position elements. Hope, it helps :)

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.fc {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.leftImage {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/270360/pexels-photo-270360.jpeg?w=940&h=650&dpr=2&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb");
  background-position: 45%;
}

.rightImage {
  width: 50%;
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9d/BWV605.png");
  background-position: center;
}

div.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.left:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 150, 255, 0.8);
}

div.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transition: background-color 0.25s ease;
}

div.right:hover {
  background-color: rgba(204, 0, 0, 0.8);
}


}
```

```html
<div class="fc">
  <div class="leftImage">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="rightImage">
    <div class="right">
      <p>Test.</p>
    </div>
  </div>



</div>
```